# Devise, undefined `resource_params' for a modify controller

Tags: devise, controller

I'm using Devise for my users. And I want to change the redirection after sending them a mail to change their password. So I have created a personal controller users/passwords_controller

```
 class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/password
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

  def edit
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  protected

    def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      root_url
    end

    def assert_reset_token_passed
      if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
        set_flash_message(:error, :no_token)
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
end
```

The probleme is the controller doesn't know 'resource_params' anymore (in the first line of 'create').

I really don't know how to fix. Where should I put the resource?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace 'resource_params' with 'params' and 'resource_name' with 'params[resource_name]'.
It seems logic when you know the answer...